# Что означает ошибка: no match for ‘operator!=’

Tags: c++

Дает при

```
while (k != EOF)
```

> `no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘k != -0x000000001’`

**Добавлено из комментария**.

```
vector < string > vecquest(500);
ifstream filequest("questions_.txt");
string k;
filequest >> k;
while (k != EOF) {
    vecquest.push_back(k);
}
```

Comment: Возникает вопрос: а что такое k?

Comment: Мне нужно читать из файла список вопросов. Как мне поступать? без цикла оно читает только первую строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

k - это объект типа string, EOF - целочисленное значение.. Оператор != не перегружен для аргументов, один из которых string, другой int.

Писать можно, например, так:

```
vector < string > vecquest();
ifstream filequest("questions_.txt");
string k;

while (getline (filequest, k) ) {
    vecquest.push_back(k);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: Если ответ подошел, голосуем "за"